# Type punning: int[] and struct { int … }

Tags: c, c99, memory-alignment, abi, type-punning

I wonder if it is safe, according to the C99 standard, to interpret such a struct:

```
struct my_struct_t {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
```

as an `int[3]`. I.e. is this code snippet sane for all ABIs?

```
struct my_struct_t f;
int *i = &f.a;
i[0] = 1; // f.a == 1
i[1] = 2; // f.b == 2
i[2] = 3; // f.c == 3
```

As far as I understand the standard, the compiler is allowed to add padding after members in a struct, but there must not be any padding inside an array. Am I getting that right? (If I am, then the code example would yield undefined behavior.)

Comment: It's officially unsafe, but will probably work on any sane implementation, as there's no reason to have different padding rules for int arrays and int fields in a struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only real "answer" to this is a citation:

C11, 6.7.2.1:

> There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning. (paragraph 15)
>   There may be unnamed padding at the end of a structure or union. (paragraph 17)

C11, 6.2.5:

> An array type describes a contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects with a particular member object type (paragraph 20)

Since the subscript operator is exactly equivalent to a pointer arithmetic operation, it cannot take account of padding (external to the type of the target object, anyway) where any may exist, and in a struct, it may.

Comment: Thank you! Your quotes are exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Kay essential bookmark material: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

Answer (score 3):

As `int`s are, well, `int`-aligned, I think it should work (and it does on my Intel x86-64 with gcc on Linux) on most platforms.

You can check if it works at compile time:

```
static_assert(offsetof(struct my_struct_t, c) == 2*sizeof(int));
```

Iff this assertion doesn't fail, the standard guarantees that you're safe (if I'm not terribly mistaken, but I can't think of anything making it UB).

Comment: +1, the static assert would find errors. (I mostly care about obscure, cheap embedded systems. :-)

Comment: **Note** I rethought this issue, and I now think (assuming the static assertion succeeds), it is as much UB as the “struct hack”. Which IMO is conforming, but many people disagree (including the standard committee), although there's no conforming implementation proving me wrong.